# Ubuntu 18.04 - Default behavior to minimize all windows and drad-n-drop file to 'background' window?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell

If do not install any Gnome Extension, what is Ubuntu-way to minimize all windows or drad-n-drop file to 'background' window which is blocked by others (For example I need to copy file from some maximized Nautilus window some Nautilus window in background on same Desktop. Or open file from Nautilus using drag-n-drop in some text-editor like gedit\sublime when window of last in background regarding to Nautilus)?

Comment: I am afraid your question isn't quite clear. "*to minimize all windows*" I get, but what is "*...or drad-n-drop file to 'background' window which is blocked by others (In case if I open couple maximized windows on same Desktop)*" <- not sure even how that line is organized. Please rephrase, include commas etc.

Comment: @Jacob Vlijm, thank You. Added additional info. I mean behavior when you need drag file from some forwarded maximized window to copy or open it with some background Nautilus or another app window. In general copy from maximized Nautilus to desktop.